# devise token auth errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I currently have a Rails 5 app running using Devise Token Auth, it is deployed on heroku.

Signing in and signing up all works fine, however, if restart the application, the next *sign in*, gives me a 500, with the following error.. Any ideas?

I have narrowed the bug down, it only happens on Heroku.
When running locally in production mode it is fine.

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.42/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:42:in `[]='
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.42/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

devise initalizer:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = 'xxx'
```

devise token auth initalizer:

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
  config.token_lifespan = 1.year
end
```

Profile.rb (model which handles auth):

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

Longer stack trace

```
2017-08-21T13:47:59.917645+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-21T13:47:59.917547 #4]  INFO -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for 82.163.112.30 at 2017-08-21 13:47:59 +0000
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165030+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165036+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2017-08-21T13:47:59.925118+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-21T13:47:59.925047 #4]  INFO -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as */*
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165031+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165036+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:47:59.925184+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-21T13:47:59.925134 #4]  INFO -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76]   Parameters: {"email"=>"rob@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"rob@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165032+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165036+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:47:59.976389+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-08-21T13:47:59.976252 #4] DEBUG -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76]   Profile Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE (email = 'rob@example.com' AND provider='email') ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165032+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165037+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.163017+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-08-21T13:48:00.162930 #4]  INFO -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 238ms (ActiveRecord: 19.2ms)
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165033+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.164815+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-21T13:48:00.164748 #4] FATAL -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76]   
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165033+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.164880+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-21T13:48:00.164820 #4] FATAL -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] IndexError (string not matched):
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165034+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.164933+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-21T13:48:00.164884 #4] FATAL -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76]   
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165034+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165028+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-08-21T13:48:00.164957 #4] FATAL -- : [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.42/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:42:in `[]='
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165035+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
2017-08-21T13:48:00.165029+00:00 app[web.1]: [8f6962a7-f07c-4754-959c-c51dafa37d76] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.42/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:42:in `create'
```

Comment: Looks connected to the Token `expiry` value. Did you setup an expiry value?

Comment: Within the DeviseTokenAuth initializer, I have set   config.token_lifespan = 1.year
is that what you mean?

Comment: The documentation mentions `expiry` (more CORS related) https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Comment: Can you share more of your code and config (such as devise configuration)?

Comment: have added more to the question, let me know if you need more

Comment: Can you show the full error? You only posted a partial stacktrace (I can't see the actual error message)

Comment: Have added a longer stack trace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to my migration fixed it:

```
reversible do |direction|
  direction.up do
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.tokens = nil
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```